# Which activity's event occurs when user closes the application via Task Manager?

Tags: android

... by removing the application from RAM.

How to catch this event?
I need this because I keep track midnight by using AlarmManager, and at midnight app does some actions. In the method onDestroy () of main activity, I stop tracking midnight. But if user closes application via TaskManager then I cannot stop tracking and user gets error at next midnight.

Sorry for my English.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which activity's event occurs when user closes the application via Task Manager? ... by removing the application from RAM.

There is no event. Your process is just terminated.

> How to catch this event?

You cannot catch this event.

> I need this because I keep track midnight by using AlarmManager, and at midnight app does some actions. In the method onDestroy () of main activity, I stop tracking midnight. But if user closes application via TaskManager then I cannot stop tracking and user gets error at next midnight.

I would recommend coming up with a better approach. Relying upon the user pressing BACK is not a good plan, as there are a few ways that your process will wind up being terminated without the user ever pressing BACK from your activity (or otherwise causing it to be destroyed).

Answer (score 1):

If the user is using something like [Advanced Task Killer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rechild.advancedtaskkiller&feature=search_result) to end an task, there's nothing you can do besides educating the user that Android handles task management automatically and that they shouldn't use apps like that since they are harmful.

If the user is using the 4.0 Task Switcher and swiping away the task, all that is called is `finish()`.